# How do I get all the arrays numbers when printf 10 colums and 10 rows?

Tags: c

How do i make the printf("%d, veck[i]); print out all 100 numbers of the array instead of only 1-10?

```
int vek[100];
    for(int a=0;a<10;a++){
        for(int i=0;i<10;i++){
                printf("%d ", vek[i]); //only shows numbers 1-10
        }
     printf("\n");
     }
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should change the index of vek.

```
printf("%d ", vek[10* a + i]);
```

Comment: Thank you workd great. Coudl you please jsut explain whats happening in that code?

Comment: @anon ... it multiples `a` by `10`, then adds `i` to that? Not sure what else there is to explain.

Comment: yeayea i understand that . What i mean i dont understand how that gives me all the 100 numbers. Sorry im new into coding

Comment: Sure. You can think of 'a' as iterating over the tens place of the 100 numbers of 'i' as iterating over the ones place. To get a number given 'a', which is the number of tens, and 'i', which is the number of ones, you can write '10*a + 'i'. You can verify that this will print out all of the numbers.

Comment: @anon Have you tried pretending to be the computer, and "running" your code like the computer would? Hopefully you'll see why it works.

Answer (score 1):

I like to add a utility function when I play with multi-dimensional arrays in C.  So, I have a function that takes the number of rows, and the x and y coordinates of interest.  So, I get something like this:

```
int get_item(int *matrix, int num_rows, int x, int y)
{
    return matrix[num_rows * x + y];
}
```

In your case, you'd call it like this:

```
printf("%d ", get_item(vek, 10, a, i));
```

You can also have a similar put_item function as well.

Answer (score 1):

The problem here is your array is a line, but you want to print a square.

The indices of the array might be laid out like this:

```
0  1  2  3  4  5 ...
```

But you want said indices to be printed to the screen like this:

```
 0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9
10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19
20 21 22 23 24 25 26 27 28 29
.
.
.
```

Notice the difference between each row going down a column is 10. `i` takes care of 0-9 going across, so `a` needs to take care of 0,10,20,... going down.

Wait a minute, that's multiplication. Given that `a` has the values 0, 1, 2, 3, ..., `a*10` gives us 0, 10, 20, 30, ...

If you're still confused, try subtracting the value of `i` when each number is printed. Or, write out a list of values `a` and `i` will have each time the printf is executed.

One of the hardest parts of learning how to program is not actually learning the language; it's learning how to think about problems, and how to visualize what's going on. Or, if you prefer, how to make the magic not be magic.